# Need sqlite Query with substring

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I want to fetch records from sqlite database table called messages.
I have a column named like Message_dated in the form of following "Jan 20, 2015 10:31:23". But in the cursor it is giving as it is.But now i want only date from message_dated column i dont want time.I am using to call query like following.But it is giving full date and time.

```
ColumnName = DatabaseHelper.TABLE_MSGS.COL_MESSAGE_DATED,
ColumnId =  DatabaseHelper.TABLE_MSGS.COL_MESSAGE_DATED
String[] columns = new String[] {
                DatabaseHelper.TABLE_MSGS.COL_MESSAGE_ID + " as _id",
                columnName, columnID };
cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_MESSAGES_NAME,
                    columns, null, null, columnID, null, null);
```

Please tell me how can i do it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't retrieve it without time because a date object is already found to return that, however you can manipulate it so you can store it in a string and use it in a different format using the code bellow:

```
String input = "Jan 20, 2015 10:31:23";
DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input);
DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String output = outputFormatter.format(date);
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: No here what i am doing is i am sending directly cursor to expandable listview so it divides groups and childs.For group data i am getting group cursor and passing as it is to expandable adapter.Now what i want is i need to fetch data inside query only..